# CSGO changelevel after match ends

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive, source-engine

When i use the `changelevel`command, it instantly ends the current game and changes to the next map.

Is there a console command to set the next level after a match has ended. e.g. wait until after the match has ended and the scoreboard has displayed, then changelevel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just looking for things built into the game:

- The `nextlevel` command will change to the specified map at the end of the current round.  Meaning that it will cut the current map short.
- Setting the `mp_endmatch_votenextmap` cvar to 1 will cause a vote to pop up at the end of the current map, but it uses the maps specified in your gamemodes_server.txt for the current game mode to populate that vote list.  In other words, you can't specify the map directly.

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not possible without server mods.

The only things you can do is using the maplist.txt or mapcycle.txt and set the rotation there. They can both be found in your *./csgo/* main directory.